# How to select based on custom column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

```
SELECT  
    dbo.Customers.FirstName as Firstname, dbo.Customers.LastName as Lastname, 
    dbo.Customers.Phone as Phone,  dbo.Guarantors.FirstName as Guarantor Firstname, 
    dbo.Guarantors.LastName as Guarantor Lastname, 
    dbo.Guarantors.Phone as Guarantor Phone, 
    SUM(dbo.PaymentHistory.PaymentAmount) - SUM(dbo.PaymentHistory.PayedAmount) as Debt
FROM    
    dbo.Credits 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.PaymentHistory ON dbo.Credits.ID = dbo.PaymentHistory.CreditID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Customers ON dbo.Credits.CustomerID = dbo.Customers.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.CreditGuarantors ON dbo.Credits.ID = dbo.CreditGuarantors.CreditID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Guarantors ON dbo.CreditGuarantors.GuarantorID = dbo.Guarantors.ID
WHERE   
    (dbo.Credits.Status = 0) AND 
    (dbo.PaymentHistory.PaymentDay <= GETDATE()) AND 
    (dbo.Credits.BranchID = 1)
GROUP BY 
    dbo.Customers.LastName, dbo.Customers.Phone,
    dbo.Credits.ID, dbo.Customers.FirstName, 
    dbo.Guarantors.FirstName, dbo.Guarantors.LastName, 
    dbo.Guarantors.Phone
```

So I want to add 1 more rule, `where Debt !=0`. but I got error, can u help me with that ?? I want to get debt that is not 0, the person name who has debt

Comment: ,What error shows

Comment: It's good programming practice to list the GROUP BY columns in the same order as they appear in the SELECT list.

Comment: thanks for the note, can u tell me is there any difference or it's just ethic ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `HAVING` clause . Add this to the end of the query:

```
HAVING SUM(dbo.PaymentHistory.PaymentAmount) - SUM(dbo.PaymentHistory.PayedAmount) <> 0
```

Comment: Thanks, can u tell me what `HAVING` actualy does ?

Answer (score 2):

Because this involves aggregation functions, you want to use a `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING SUM(dbo.PaymentHistory.PaymentAmount) - SUM(dbo.PaymentHistory.PayedAmount) <> 0
```

Or:

```
HAVING SUM(dbo.PaymentHistory.PaymentAmount) <> - SUM(dbo.PaymentHistory.PayedAmount)
```

Note:  Your query would be easier to write and to read if you used table aliases.

Comment: Thenks for the note and for help